# Move comments to chat is failing

Tags: bug, comments, chat, moderator-tools

While processing flags this morning, I attempted to move an [extended discussion in the comments to chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076574/why-is-my-repaint-method-not-repainting) but the migration of the comments is failing. No error is popping up, nothing is happening.

Can we please fix it?

Comment: To clarify, which of the following are true: **a.:** a chat room was created, **b.:** no comments were migrated to the newly created chat room, **c.:** the original comments no longer exist.

Comment: @canon at this point `c` because I purged all the comments after the question was successfully answered and accepted. But previously, `d` - none of the above.